# HTML5 canvas poor performance with 2000+ images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In my game using HTML5 Canvas, there's a lot of objects.
When I draw ~2000 images and more using `drawImage()` I got a very poor performance and a big cpu usage (25%)

My game resolution is `1920x1080`; I'm using `requestAnimationFrame` and only the `drawImage()` function

In this `pixiJS` benchmark (http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/), I still have 60 fps and 15% of cpu usage with 30k (30 000) bunnies

How are they doing? How can I lower my CPU usage and keep a high FPS (60-40 fps is good)
Please note that I can't use the "virtual multiple canvas" method because it's an isometric game, and depending on the user position, some objects should be draw after or before the user.

*edit*:

**Profiling**:

[image: screenshot - http://prnt.sc/ea061p]

My container class (typescript) which sort the objects and then draw them (as seen on the profiling)

```
export default class Container {
    private Objects: Array<any> = [];
    private Context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
    private Texts: Array<any> = [];
    private Points: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(Context: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
        this.Context = Context;
    }

    public drawImage(index: number, z: number, img: HTMLImageElement, sx?: number, sy?: number, swidth?: number, sheight?: number, x?: number, y?: number, width?: number, height?: number) {
        this.Objects.push({
            index: index,
            z: z, 
            img: img, 
            sx: sx, 
            sy: sy, 
            swidth: swidth, 
            sheight: sheight, 
            x: x, 
            y: y, 
            width: width, 
            height: height
        });

        return this.Objects[this.Objects.length - 1];
    }

    public fillText(text: string, color: string, x: number, y: number) {
        this.Texts.push({
            text: text,
            x: x,
            color: color,
            y: y
        });
    }

    public fillPoint(color: string, size: number, x: number, y: number) {
        this.Points.push({
            color: color,
            width: size,
            height: size,
            x: x,
            y: y
        });
    }

    public Draw() {
        this.Objects.sort((a, b) => {
            return (a.index - b.index) == 0 ? (a.z - b.z == 0 ? (a.LayerId ? (a.LayerId < b.LayerId ? -1 : (a.LayerId > b.LayerId ? 1 : 0)) : 0) : a.z - b.z) : (a.index - b.index);
        });

        for(var id in this.Objects) {
            var object = this.Objects[id];

            if(object.swidth == undefined) {
                this.Context.drawImage(object["img"], object["sx"], object["sy"]);
            } else if(object.x == undefined) {
                this.Context.drawImage(object["img"], object["sx"], object["sy"], object["swidth"], object["sheight"]);
            } else {
                this.Context.drawImage(object["img"], object["sx"], object["sy"], object["swidth"], object["sheight"], object["x"], object["y"], object["width"], object["height"]);
            }
        }

        this.Objects = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: if you look in source coude you can see that they are using 2D WebGL engine which you can use too: http://www.pixijs.com/
I am not sure how does it work, but you can create also games like duke nukem in WebGL. :D

Comment: You should be using profiling tools to find the bottlenecks in your code. If you can find those, then you can show us them (in a [mcve]).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have alerdy profiled my game, but here's it http://prnt.sc/ea061p

Comment: If you want help, you need to [edit] your question to include that analysis *and the code where it is happening*. We obviously can't help you optimize code if we can't see the code. Please read [ask], and the link I posted earlier.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan question edited

Comment: As Kuba points out, pixijs uses WebGL to drive the graphics. WebGL and 2D are not comparable performance wise. You can do a numerous thing to gain performance for 2D (pre-rendering spritesheets with all variations, use integers for position, size and calculations, turn off image-smoothing and alpha channel, pooling/reuse objects, reduce overall surface size etc.) but you won't be able to achieve the same rate as with WebGL.

Answer (score 1):

### 2000 sprites for top end platforms only,

Bunnies don't count.

Wow 30,0000 sprites is a lot... wow..., but wait, they don't rotate, scale, or even have basic FX like alpha fade. One tiny sprite (26 by 37) on a tiny part of the screen all doing the very same thing. Come now a modern GPU can do much better than that with pixel rates of 40,000Mpps (Mega pixels per second) common. The demo is just at 2000Mpps, for such simple sprites you should be seeing a quarter of a million tiny bunnies madly bouncing about.

#### Why is the bunnie demo so slow?

The bottleneck for the bunnies is the CPU and javascript. You say 15% CPU usage. Open up the task manager and look in the performance tab (turn on logical processors) now start the demo and you will see one core's use start to climb. When that core hits 100% (maybe 15% of overall system on 8 Core machine) the bunny frame rate starts to drop. This is the evidence that the Javascript execution can not keep up. If however the demo begins to slow down before a core reaches 100% then the GPU is old and slow.

#### The simplest javascript is too slow

Look at the javascript that moves the bunnies, it's a flat loop that updates each bunny in turn and then updates the vertex buffers binds them issue a draw and does it all again, its as simple as it can get and yet it is still the performance bottleneck.

So yes 30,000 bunnies is Wow a lot, but imagine now you wanted to add a bunny with a gun, and all the support code to test for bullets, bunny fur flying death FX. dead bunnies :( ohhh the rodenity... just a simple shoot-em up. You can try it by downloading the demo and changing the code yourself. 30000 bunnies, One bunny with a gun, the 60fps will very quickly start to drop for every bullet the gun toten bunny pops off.

#### Your game.

For a Javascript 2D Context API canvas game you should be budgeting no more than 1000 maybe 1200,1300 at max sprites per frame. Unlike the bunnies these are proper sprites that can be rotated, scaled, have independent alpha and depending on the hardware  some limited composite operation. eg lighten for explosions.

If you think you can get more sprites by using webGL you are not going to get much more than that budget. Proper sprites (Rotated, scaled, Fx,..) need a lot of support code. The 2D canvas API does it all for you using native interfaces, if you go down the WebGL path that just means you have to take on the extra burden of low level GPU management on top of your javascript's already flat out job.

There are opportunities for worthwhile performance increase (by off loading game logic to the GPU) but you had better be a slick A grade experienced coder to be able to pull that off for every device under the sun.

So stick to the 2D API as it`s apparent slow performance masks an awesome high performance, easy to use, very robust, well tested, extremely widely supported hardware accelerated graphics rendering interface.

Oh and maybe use javascript rather than typescript which for games is just more CPU cycle chewing bloat you real do not need.

---

> **Note** : My criticism of the bunnie demo is only on that demo's use of gradiouse performance stats. PixiJS is a very well written library, among the very best available for javascript game development. IMO

Comment: I can't use less images per frame, these are objects that the user can drop them in his plot, and if I limit the number of objects the game will become not too good :| 
So how could I keep this awesome high performance with more than 2000 images/sprites?

Comment: You need to find a way to reduce the load, half the res, half the frame rate. Your game should run well on the lowest level device you intend it to be played on. To keep the performance is easy, use a faster PC with more RAM and better GPU. Looking at your code there is plenty of room for improvement. Learn how to profile your code, (the browser CPU profile is at best a rough estimate and at worst a downright lie don't trust it). Without information we can only guess and make suggestions but I am guessing you can lose 20% or more of the rendered pixels and not even notice.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 canvas is never performing well when using it with many ( 1000+ ) images. 
I think javascript will perform better in that situation.

But if you still want to use HTML5, maybe this will help:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/